# jQuery - Toggle class on $(this) and remove class on all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my jQuery snippet that I am using:

```
$('.panel-title').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.state').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

**UPDATE** - Edit the fiddle to match more what I am dealing with

Here is a fiddle showing you what I am talking about
https://jsfiddle.net/ke1hwn7f/9/

What I need to be able to do is toggle a class back and forth. That is pretty straight foward. But I also need to set it so that if that class already exists on an element I need to remove it.

So in the fiddle you can see that when you click "This is heading 4" it toggles the "colorChange" class. But then you click "This is heading 2" I need it to toggle that one green but also remove the class from "This is heading 4" (or anywhere else that it might exist) hopefully before it toggles the element that was just clicked.

Is there a way for me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
$('.panel-title').click(function(){
  // If the clicked element has the rotate class, remove the rotate class from EVERY .panel-title>.state element
  if ($(this).find('.state').hasClass('rotate')){
    $('.panel-title').find('.state').removeClass('rotate');
  }
  // Else, the element doesn't have the rotate class, so we remove it from every element before applying it to the element that was clicked
  else {
    $('.panel-title').find('.state').removeClass('rotate');
    $(this).find('.state').addClass('rotate');
  }
});
```

If it has the class, remove it to every title, else, remove it to all but add it to the one you clicked after.

Comment: This nailed it!!! And you answered it before I edit my fiddle. So much for other peoples grumbling that the question changed so I needed to create a new post. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Happy it helped :-), I'll edit it to add some comment for future references

Comment: And btw the question hasn't changed, you gave all the information needed, you said the fiddle was a reference, you didn't said it was the problem ;-)